# I'm what you do when you're off on a trip - What am I?

Tags: riddle, rhyme, homonym

I'm what you do when you're off on a trip,

I am a proud parent to an off the block chip,

You know me best when you've naught to do,

You may find me when when you shouldn't too,

I love games but most games that I love are flat,

Flat too is a clue on it's own, how 'bout that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are

> board/bored

I'm what you do when you're off on a trip,

> You board a plane when you are on a trip

I am a proud parent to an off the block chip,

**OP:**

> Motherboard :)

You know me best when you've naught to do,

> You are bored when you've naught to do

You may find me when when you shouldn't too,

**OP:**

> e.g. important safety meetings at work...

I love games but most games that I love are flat,

> Board games are flat

Flat too is a clue on it's own, how 'bout that?

> Boards are flat

Comment: I am.  Well done +1. I've edited to fill in the couple of blanks.

Comment: There are two lines I couldn't match to the answer ("proud parent" and "you may find me").  Are those filler or is there some meaning to them?

Comment: see my edits for those before explanations.